# How to invert the result of this for loop pyramid?

Tags: python, for-loop

Our professor wants us to perform our previous problem of inverting the result of a pyramid of numbers, given a certain height, but now using for loops. I seem to be doing something wrong with my code.

What I have so far:

```
size = int(input("Height: "))
for num in range(size, 0, -1):
    for num2 in range(1, num + 1):
        print(num2, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Desired Output:

```
87654321
7654321
654321
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `for num2 in range(num, 0, -1):`. You already have an inverse range in the outer loop; not sure why you didn't do that for the inner loop as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need a descending range within a descending range.

This should do it:

```
height = int(input('Height: '))

for i in range(height, 0, -1):
    print(*map(str, range(i, 0, -1)))
```

**Output:**

```
Height: 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reverse your second for loop to achieve your the desired output.
Try like this:

```
size = int(input("Height: "))
for num in range(size, 0, -1):
   for num2 in range(1, num + 1)[::-1]:
      print(num2, end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: `range(1, num + 1)[::-1]` seems the convoluted way of writing `range(num, 0, -1)`. Or even `reversed(1, num+1)`.

Comment: @9769953 yeah, you are right `range(num, 0, -1)` would be good. I `range(1, num + 1)[::-1]` as she would be a beginner so, it's better for her understanding. As you know we are learning list slicing before nested for loop and etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).